# Query data through an API for one date at a time

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a Python code that will take in start and end dates and loop through one date at a time as a parameter for `start_date` to run an API query and append the data to a JSON file. Although the list of parameters has an `end_date` parameter, due to the large volume of data and the limitations put in, I can only run the API query for one day.

```
import requests
import json
import datetime

def run_query(date):
  url = "-------------"

  querystring = {"routes":"10","startDate":date}

  headers = {
     "Accept": "application/json, application/json; charset=utf-8, text/csv; charset=utf-8",
     "Authorization": "--------------------------"
  }

  response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

def main():
  start_date = input("Enter start date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
  end_date = input("Enter end date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
  start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
  end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
  delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
  with open("data1.json", "a") as f:
        delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        while (start_date <= end_date):
          data =run_query(start_date)
          json.dump(data, f)
          f.write("\n")
          start_date += delta      

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I tried this and I got a series of null values in the output JSON file.

Comment: what's your question? Are you asking iterating over dates or about nulls?